# Converting between mean time between failures and survival probabilities

Tags: probability-or-statistics

This is more of a math question, but I'm hoping some math wizard can help me map these concepts to functions in Mathematica's [reliability](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Reliability.html) API.

$f$ of my machines will experience a failure in the first 24 hours of operation. (ie, $f\approx 0.2$ from AWS spot instance interruption [rate](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/))

It takes $s$ seconds to replace this machine, during which time, all work is stopped on all machines.

I need to perform total of $w$ machine-hours of work, by using $m$ machines simultaneously.

How would I write a function that takes $w$, $m$, $s$, $f$ and returns expected time to complete the work?

```
totalTime[w_, m_, s_, f_] := If[f == 0,
   w/m,
   -43 (* not implemented *)
   ];
Print[totalTime[2, 1, 0, 0], " hours of work required"]
```

Comment: I think this is a statistics / probability question so maybe more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the math was worked out in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/579891/511

Comment: Glad it worked out! Perhaps you could summarize the answer here with a self-answer, including a pointer to the CrossValidated post.